# How to convert similarity matrix into dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: cluster-analysis, similarity

How to convert similarity matrix into dissimilarity matrix?
Example:

```
Point P1    P2   P3    P4
P1    1    0.8  0.65  0.55
P2    0.8   1    0.7   0.6
P3    0.65 0.7   1    0.9
P4    0.55 0.6   0.9    1
```

P1 and P2 are in cluster1 and P3 and P4 are in cluster2

Answer (score 5):

If your maximum similarity is 1, you can simply use

dissim(x,y) = 1 - sim(x,y)

Using "maxsim - sim" works very often.

But did you know many clustering algorithms (e.g., HAC, GDBSCAN) *can* be implemented with a similarity function, too? It's just that the typical library only implement one version.